# How to Create a pdf using syncfusion in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to create a pdf with syncfusion and using the example shown on this link:
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10673/how-to-create-a-pdf-document-in-aws-lambda

I have created a small console app and I am having issues reading the data on the line with the HELP comment. It is looking for a path rather than reading the string as shown in the example link.
Anyone who has used similar who can suggest a fix? Thanks

```
using System;
using Syncfusion.Pdf;
using Syncfusion.Pdf.Graphics;
using Syncfusion.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace pdf
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
       
            var result = GetData();
            var stream = new StreamReader(result); //----> How do I read this? HELP
            JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(stream);
            var serilizer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
            var responseText = serilizer.Deserialize(reader);

            //Convert Base64String into PDF document
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(responseText.ToString());
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("Sample.pdf", FileMode.Create);
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
            writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            writer.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Sample.pdf");
        }

        static string GetData()
        {
            //Create a new PDF document
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

            //Add a page to the document
            PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();

            //Create PDF graphics for the page
            PdfGraphics graphics = page.Graphics;

            //Set the standard font
            PdfFont font = new PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.Helvetica, 20);

            //Draw the text
            graphics.DrawString("Hello World!!!", font, PdfBrushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));

            string imagePath = Path.GetFullPath(@"Data\logo.png");

            //Load the image from the disk
            FileStream imageStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            PdfBitmap image = new PdfBitmap(imageStream);

            //Draw the image
            graphics.DrawImage(image, 30, 30, 100, 25);

            //Save the document into stream
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

            //Save the PDF document  
            document.Save(stream);
            document.Close();
         

    
            return (Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray()));
           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about returing directly the stream by `GetData` method and pass the stream to `StreamReader`.

```
static Stream GetData()
{
    ...
    // remove return (Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray()));
    return stream;
}
```